# Search functionality breaks in jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Rephrasing the question(sorry about the previous one). Jquery datatable search field is ignoring spaces. i.e 'ash h t t on cox', 'a s hton c ox' is yielding the search result 'Ashton Cox'. How to make it search an exact match(exact spelling)?

Please try searching the above terms in    `jsfiddle`http://jsfiddle.net/ryanoc/ebRXw/`

Comment: 1. please create a fiddle
2. what devtools says?

Comment: Agree with @vlio20, impossible to answer without at least an example of the table along with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Add `"oSearch": {"bSmart": false}` 
[**FIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/56/)

Answer (score 0):

disable caseInsensitive search and smart search

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: true,
        search:{
            caseInsensitive:false,
            smart:false
        }
    } );
} );
```

fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/55/